# How to calculate the maximum power of a current mode PWM controller?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm

I am working on a switch mode power supply and looking for perfect current mode PWM controller. In the datasheets of current mode PWM controllers, the maximum power at which they can be operated is not mentioned.

How can I calculate the maximum power of a current mode PWM controller?

Here is the datasheet of the [NCP1252](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/281574/ONSEMI/NCP1252.html) current mode PWM controller.

Comment: A PWM controller is the low-power section of a switching converter. A circuit like the one you mentioned can reliably operate a 10-W or a 1-kW converter without problem. That being said, some devices are more tailored for low-power application because they do not embark all the bells and whistles necessary for safely operating a high-power version or are more susceptible to noise.

Comment: This question is a bit complicated to answer properly, but the answer is that a controller just controls a power circuit, so first you have to learn enough to figure out what mosfets you can control with it at what frequencies, and based on the capabilities of those mosfets, the transformer, and the rest of the components in the power circuit.  You can't exceed the limits of any component.  Once you figure out your capabilities, P(power)=I(current)*E(voltage)

Answer (score 0):

> *In datasheets of Current Mode PWM Controller maximum power at that it
> can be operated is not mentioned*

You can make a maximum estimate of how much maximum power you can dissipate: -

[image]

So, at an ambient temperature of (say) 25 °C, you can allow the package to warm by another 125 °C before the "junction" exceeds its limit. Given that the device has a thermal resistance from internal junction to air of 180 °C per watt, the maximum power that should be dissipated in the device is 0.69 watts.

If you don't have reasonable control over the local ambient temperature around the chip (air flow etc.), it may warm the local ambient another 30 °C so maybe you should aim to dissipate no more than 0.5 watts. But, to be on the safe side I would aim for no more than 0.3 watts.

If you look a little higher up in the table above it also tells you that the maximum voltage is 28 volts and you should not allow more than 20 mA into pin 7 (Vcc). It should say pin 8 by the way; pin 7 is a typo in this data sheet.

So that implies a maximum power limit of 0.56 watts but, I'd try and run at much lower values here because it leaves very little power to activate the MOSFET you need to attach.